# Issue in ionic 3 navigation on ios emulator

Tags: ionic-framework

I have tried below 3 types of nav methods to move from Page A to Page B. When I generate a apk any one of this are working fine. But when I tried to emulate this in IOS none are working. I have used breakpoints in developer tools there is no error. Just nothing happens.

```
    // this.nav.setRoot(pagename,{},{direction:"back"});
    //this.nav.setRoot(pagename).then(() => { 
        this.nav.popToRoot();  
    });
    // this.nav.push(pagename);
```

This is  complete function.

```
openPage(page){

  let nav = this.app.getActiveNavs()[0];

    let activeView = nav.getActive();

    if (activeView.name != page) {
        if(page == "editCustomer"){ 
            this.openEditCustomerModal();
        } else if(page == "feedBackPage"){
            this.openRatingModal();
        }else{
           this.nav.setRoot(page,{},{direction:"back"}); 
        }
        this.closeMenu();
    }else{
        this.menuCtrl.close();
    } 
  }
```

Comment: Hi, I've edited your question to format the code and make it easier to read. You should do that yourself next time. Still I have no idea what you are asking. Please [edit] your question to clarify. You may want to take the [tour] to understand how this site work and how to ask good questions, so that you get the most value out of it.

Comment: It seems like your expected is in your else block you are trying to `setRoot`. I don't think you need to `popToRoot`. This alone should be just fine `this.nav.setRoot(page)`. Also if you have a/the device connected you can open safari dev tools and check out the console there.